# Syntax error on line 494 of httpd.conf: Cannot load .../php5apache2_2.dll into server

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I have been learning PHP. I had installed Apache-server (not in a combination-suite like USBWebserver). Now I'm trying to put my sites on a portable stick, using USBWebserver. I already used that program before to carry MySQL databases with me (and Apache worked as well, cause I used the included PHPMyAdmin for managing the databases.), but now it doesn't work anymore. When I start the program, I keep having the text saying Apache is offline.

I've tried to open Apache using the command line (don't know what that would do, but, it's just a try). I got an error message saying

```
Syntax error on line 494 of C:/.../httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/.../php5apache2_2.dll into server:
(The following is translated from Dutch)
An initialization routine of the dynamic link library (dll-file) has failed.
```

Line 494 says this:

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/Users/School/Downloads/USBWebserver v8_en/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

My first Apache installation (its service) is not running. The ports are different. And I also uninstalled the service (using the `httpd.exe -k uninstall` command);

What can be the problem? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache shouldn't start if it's unable to load any of its modules.

Make sure the version of the windows apache PHP library (php5apache*.dll) is built for the version of apache you are using and that it is in the correct path and not corrupt.

Comment: That can not be the problem, cause USBWebserver has already worked, I also already downloaded a new version, which also didn't work. Thanks for helping though.

Comment: I'm wrong. I changed changed the content of the php directory to that of the php directory downloaded from php.net. Now version 8.0 works. In version 8.5, I get errors about extension it can't find (even though the error mentions the right path).